# A problem with back-propagation equation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

Excerpt from some [machine learning course notes](http://www.wikicoursenote.com/wiki/Stat841f11#Backpropagation_.28Finding_Optimal_Weights.29):

[image]

I'm a little confused about the $\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial u_{il}} =  z_l$ part. Shouldn't it be $\sum_{l} z_l$?

Comment: no think about it intuitively. you are asking how does the activation of unit i change with the weight connecting unit l (fixed l) to unit i. So the notation is a bit bad in using l both as a 'loop' variable and to specify a specific unit

Comment: Could you elaborate in an answer? Thanks!